# how to place an app developed in j2me in google store?

Tags: ios, mobile, java-me, android

I am a newbie in mobile app dev. I have been given an app to write as assignment and it is suggested that I should use Java/J2ME and an android phone is required. Well, if I develop it in j2me 
 1. Will I be use it in android phone?
 2. will I be able to place it in the Google Play Store?
 3. Will I be able to place in other stores such as Apple store and use it in IOS?
 4. Moreover, if it is possible to run it on android phone and I place it in play store, if I wish to monetize it, will I be able to place ads such as one provided google, the famous admob?

Is it really sound to use J2ME or is the Android API better?

Answer (score 3):

No is the answer. You can create library ie as jar and use it in android. Android uses in addition to java file. xml layout.Moreover apk is an extension which is compressed binary format of resource(xml),values manifest with set of permissions to access.For eg: Internet permission means you want to use as

and every app extension file will vary. So it's better to use cross mobile platform.One code to support in many device.

Sencha Touch

Titanium

Jquery Mobile etc.,

Answer (score 2):

If You are using sencha to develop your app you can deploy it in all platforms..or else you have to code seperately for android and ios..
Once your app is ready you can sell it through playstore(android) or istore(i phone) by creating an account in both..

Answer (score 2):

> Will I be use it in android phone?

No, unless you find some sort of "player" for J2ME.

> will I be able to place it in the Google Play Store?

No, unless you find some sort of "player" for J2ME that you can license that will give you a distributable APK as output.

> Will I be able to place in other stores such as Apple store and use it in IOS?

No, as iOS does not support J2ME.

> Moreover, if it is possible to run it on android phone and I place it in play store, if I wish to monetize it, will I be able to place ads such as one provided google, the famous admob?

No, unless you find some sort of "player" for J2ME that you can license that will give you a distributable APK as output and allows you to embed ads.

> Is it really sound to use J2ME

Only if you want to run your app on a feature phone that supports J2ME. I am not aware of any current smartphone platform that supports J2ME.